# Any reason why this div would not animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I cannot understand why a specific div (id=error) won't animate here's the div:

```
<asp:Content ID="SContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainMessageContent" runat="server">
    <div class="ui-widget" id="widget">
            <div id="error" runat="server" visible="false" style="padding: 0 .7em; margin-bottom:5px;">
                <p><span id="msgSpan" runat="server" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
                <strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here's the jquery:

```
$("#MainMessageContent_error").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFB24B"
    },
                3000,
                function () {
                    $("#MainMessageContent_error").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 3000);
                    $('#MainMessageContent_error').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    });
                }
     );
```

It fades out but it does not animate.

Comment: Do you mean changing of background color?

Comment: @VisioN - Yes it fades out but the background doesnt change is it due to the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern solution which you might wanna try is:

```
<style type="text/css">
#MainMessageContent_error {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 3s;
    transition: background-color 3s;

    background-color: #FFB24B;
}

#MainMessageContent_error.animate {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>
```

And do a `.addClass('animate');` on it.

If you wish to go back, simply `.removeClass('animate');` it.

This gives a smooth animation which is less laggy. Before someone says "What about IE versions?" do note that this solution still works, but without the animation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use animate effect you need to plug-in [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) library. In the core jquery library there is no such method.